# Python NLTK: how to lemmatize text include verb in english?

Tags: python, nltk

I want to lemmatize this text and it is only lemmatize the nouns i need to lemmatize the verbs also

```
    >>> import nltk, re, string
    >>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
    >>> from urllib import urlopen
    >>> url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/evandrix/nltk_data/master/corpora/europarl_raw/english/ep-00-01-17.en"
    >>> raw = urlopen(url).read()
    >>> raw ="".join(l for l in raw if l not in string.punctuation)
    >>> tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
    >>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
    >>> lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    >>> lem = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(t) for t in tokens]
    >>> lem[:20]
['Resumption', 'of', 'the', 'session', 'I', 'declare', 'resumed', 'the', 'session', 'of', 'the', 'European', 'Parliament', 'adjourned', 'on', 'Friday', '17', 'December', '1999', 'and']
```

here verb like resumed it suppose to be resume can you tell me what i should to do for lemmatize the whole text

Comment: Please fix your code ident!

Comment: i dont know how it's my first time to ask

Comment: Simply paste the code as it is , then select the code, then simply click on the `{}` symbol.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the `pos` parameter in wordnetlemmatizer:

```
>>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
>>> from nltk import pos_tag
>>> wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> wnl.lemmatize('resumed')
'resumed'
>>> wnl.lemmatize('resumed', pos='v')
u'resume'
```

Here's a complete code, with `pos_tag` function:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
>>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
>>> wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> txt = """Resumption of the session I declare resumed the session of the European Parliament adjourned on Friday 17 December 1999 , and I would like once again to wish you a happy new year in the hope that you enjoyed a pleasant festive period ."""
>>> [wnl.lemmatize(i,j[0].lower()) if j[0].lower() in ['a','n','v'] else wnl.lemmatize(i) for i,j in pos_tag(word_tokenize(txt))]
['Resumption', 'of', 'the', 'session', 'I', 'declare', u'resume', 'the', 'session', 'of', 'the', 'European', 'Parliament', u'adjourn', 'on', 'Friday', '17', 'December', '1999', ',', 'and', 'I', 'would', 'like', 'once', 'again', 'to', 'wish', 'you', 'a', 'happy', 'new', 'year', 'in', 'the', 'hope', 'that', 'you', u'enjoy', 'a', 'pleasant', 'festive', 'period', '.']
```

Comment: Why is the if statement needed in the list comprehension?

Comment: Because there are cases where the POS don't fall into a wordnet POS category, e.g. pronouns, ("I", "PN") or determiners, ("the", "DT")